# How can I connect an old corrugated style supply line to a new faucet?

Tags: plumbing

I am in the process of replacing faucet and concerned that existing supply line (see pic) may not make a water tight connection to new hardware.

Can someone give me more information about how this corrugated style supply works: any old manual or plumbing tutorial where connection to this supply line is taught?

My preference is to connect this line to another modern supply line such as braided steel type. How can I reliably connect these two lines?

I would like not to cut off and replace a brand new shutoff valve because I don't have a long pipe to work with.  (The picture included is not the real one but from another sink not being repaired.)

Here is the connection at the corrugated supply line and another from new faucet handle.  My goal is to only connect these two lines.

[image: faucet connection under sink]
[image: corrugated line connector detail]
[image: water line shutoff with corrugated line attached]

Comment: The ridged pipe is just a covering for a flexible pipe.  It should used common plumbing fittings at the ends.

Comment: You should not need to cut off the old valve to be able to replace it with a new one. Show us a close-up of the bottom of the valve.

Comment: @crip659 This pipe looks to me like bendable stainless corrugated pipe without any internal tube/liner, not a covering. I've seen it used for decades-old under-sink hookups and just last year to connect water lines to the fittings on a new replacement water heater. You're right that it should have a standard fitting on each end.

Comment: Search for "Corrugated Stainless Steel Water Connector" for more info

Comment: You've added some good detail, but I still don't see the problem. (A properly focused photo would help.) Are the supply and faucet fittings incompatible? At a glance they look like they'd match up nicely. FYI, the supply has a compression fitting in it, so no tape is needed on the threads. That's not where the seal occurs.

Comment: @isherwood supply has a rubber washer or something that was damaged when I remove it from the old faucet.  That washer does not matter?

Comment: @isherwood I have also added a different photo of supply line.  I think the water will leak from supply line because even though copper threads from it match with faucet fitting, copper head on the supply has no seal on the supply line

Comment: That's brass, not copper, and it's still badly out of focus. Look into how to use your phone or camera properly, please. The washer makes the seal, so replace it if needed. That seems fairly obvious, which is why I'm confused about your question.

Comment: I think @isherwood is talking about getting the fitting with washer at corrugated end in focus. Your photo was focused on the corrugated tubing, not the end fitting.

Comment: Is the corrugated tubing permanently attached to the shut off valve, or is there a fitting at that connection that can be unscrewed? A photo of that connection would be a big help.

Comment: In the background of your top photo it looks like the other (cold water) faucet supply is successfully connected to a similar corrugated stainless steel supply line. The same type of connection should work on the hot side, as long as you make sure the washer inside the nut end is replaced with a proper replacement. You could take out the old washer and bring it to a hardware store to get a match. Just make sure to buy a higher-quality (silicone etc) washer that will stand up to hot water.

Comment: That's 1/2" NPT... to 3/8" compression? (like they all are.) If your valve isn't 3/8" (or w/e the other standard one is that IDK even what it is because 99% of the time it *isn't*) then the problem is the valve. And I can't tell what type of valve that is (threaded, soldered or compression) with the escutcheon in the way. Using the old supply lines? Yeah, no.

Comment: Picture of the valve showing that it's 3/8" (with the line removed)? It ain't 1/2"; that'd be the size of the pipe. Forget about w/e you have there. Go buy the thing at the store. 1/2" NPT to 3/8" compression, at say, 18" long?